# Changing the color and text of AppBar based on the currently viewed page

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a TabBarView that navigates between the pages in my app. Is there a way to change/override the text and the color of the main AppBar based on the currently viewed page, instead of creating an AppBar for each page separately?

This is how my pages are setup

My routes are defined in the main function as follows:

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            "/Home": (BuildContext context) => new first.Home(),
            "/Support": (BuildContext context) => new second.Support(),

          }
```

Tabs class

```
        class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {

          @override
          TabsState createState() => new TabsState();
        }

    class TabsState extends State<Tabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      TabController controller;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        controller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);

      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();

      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: new Text('App'), backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          bottom: new TabBar(
              controller: controller,
              tabs: <Tab>[
                new Tab (icon: new Icon(Icons.home), text: 'Home',),
                            new Tab (icon: new Icon(Icons.mail), text:'Support'),
              ]),
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            new first.Home(),
            new second.Support(),

          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified this code to add support for text and color change i guess

https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/tabbed-app-bar/

I apologize for the ugliness for the code. All I did was change all the classes to stateful widget, add an setstate icon selector, change the widget so there is an onPressed callback

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
    MainApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful,
    // meaning that it has a State object (defined below) that contains
    // fields that affect how it looks.

    // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the
    // values (in this case the title) provided by the parent (in this
    // case the App widget) and used by the build method of the State.
    // Fields in a Widget subclass are always marked "final".

    final String title;
    @override
    TabbedAppBarSample createState() => new TabbedAppBarSample();
  }
  class TabbedAppBarSample extends State<MainApp> {
    Choice _choice;
    initState(){
      super.initState();
      _choice = choices[0];
    }
    void _select(var c){
      setState((){
        _choice = c;
      });

    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        home: new DefaultTabController(

          length: choices.length,
          child: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              //dynamically create appbar colors
              backgroundColor: new Color(_choice.color),
              title: new Text(_choice.title),
              bottom: new TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
                   //change to iconbutton
                  return new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(choice.icon),
                    onPressed: (){_select(choice);},
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            body:
            new TabBarView(
              children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
                return new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: new ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class Choice {
    const Choice({ this.title, this.icon, this.color});
    final String title;
    final IconData icon;
    final num color;
  }

  const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
    const Choice(title: 'CAR', icon: Icons.directions_car, color:  0xFFE0F7FA),
    const Choice(title: 'BICYCLE', icon: Icons.directions_bike, color: 0x00ff0000),
    const Choice(title: 'BOAT', icon: Icons.directions_boat, color: 0xFF42A5F5),
    const Choice(title: 'BUS', icon: Icons.directions_bus, color: 0x0),
    const Choice(title: 'TRAIN', icon: Icons.directions_railway, color: 0xFFEFFFFF),
    const Choice(title: 'WALK', icon: Icons.directions_walk, color: 0x0000ff00),
  ];
  class ChoiceCard extends StatefulWidget {
    ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
    final Choice choice;
    @override
    _ChoiceCard createState() => new _ChoiceCard();
  }
  class _ChoiceCard extends State<ChoiceCard> {


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;

      return new Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(widget.choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
              new Text(widget.choice.title, style: textStyle),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void main() {
    runApp(new MainApp());
  }
```

I am a bit annoyed because my code above is similar to actual answer the op needed. The only difference between my code above and what the op wanted is that I added the on change to the tabcontroller instead of the button itself

Here is the code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 void main() {
   runApp(new MyApp());
 }
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new MaterialApp(
       title: 'Nothing',
       theme: new ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       ),
       home: new Tabs(),
     );
   }

 }
 class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   TabsState createState() => new TabsState();
 }
 class TabsState extends State<Tabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   TabController controller;
   //create internal state
   Choice _choice;
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     //try to make the length to
     controller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
     //add listener to add change index callback
     //https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html
     controller.addListener(_select);
     _choice = choices[0];

   }
   @override
   void dispose() {
     controller.dispose();
     super.dispose();
   }

   void _select(){
     setState((){
       _choice = choices[controller.index];
     });

   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
         appBar: new AppBar(
           centerTitle: true,
           title: new Text(_choice.title), backgroundColor: new Color(_choice.color),
           bottom: new TabBar(
               controller: controller,
               tabs: <Tab>[
                 new Tab( icon: new Icon(choices[0].icon), text: 'Home',),
                 new Tab (icon: new Icon(choices[1].icon), text:'Support'),
               ]),
         ),
         body: new TabBarView(
           controller: controller,
           children: <Widget>[
             //dummy page
             new MyHomePage(),
             new  Center( child: new Text('dummy page 2')),

           ],
         ),
     );
   }
 }
 class Choice {
   const Choice({ this.title, this.icon, this.color});
   final String title;
   final IconData icon;
   final num color;
 }
 //create a list
 const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
   const Choice(title: 'Home', icon: Icons.home, color:  0x0),
   const Choice(title: 'Support', icon: Icons.mail, color: 0xFF42A5F5),

 ];


 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
 }
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Center(
       child: new Text('dummy page'),
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: How does this differ from defining routes and navigating to them, is each choice is treated as an actual route/page ?

Comment: Next time, write that you are using navigation and routes classes to tab through your pages. I kinda need to see your code if you want a tailored solution.

I just used the tabbed bar sample to show you how to change the material color by setting a global parent state. Each ChoiceCard is a widget but it can act like a new page if you so wish. All you need to change is ChoiceCard class and add case statements to return pages in build.

If you are using the tabbar widget, you can change the onpressed callback to figure out which page you currently by setting the state

Comment: Meh I updated my code. There is little difference between my code and the code you need. I added a few extra lines so you can build it and see

Comment: Thank you sir for your great help.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a `PageView` instead of a `TabBarView`, you can specify an `onPageChanged` function that allows you to change the state, therefore rebuilding the widget.

Here's some code I'm working on, the title is changed in the appbar but the concept is fundamentally the same:

```
// Copyright 2017 <Abhi Agarwal>
// Refer to LICENSE

// Dart Imports

// Flutter Imports
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package Imports
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'
    show SharedPreferences;

// Local Imports
import '../calendar/calendar_view.dart' show CalendarView;
import '../error/error_screen.dart' show ErrorScreen;
import '../homework/homework_view.dart' show HomeworkView;
import '../loading/loading_screen.dart' show LoadingScreen;

import 'page.dart' show Page;

class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  MainView({Key key, this.initialIndex = 0, SharedPreferences prefs})
      : pages = _makePagesList(prefs),
        super(key: key);
  final int initialIndex;
  final List<Page> pages;

  static List<Page> _makePagesList(SharedPreferences prefs) => <Page>[
        CalendarView.page(),
        new Page(
          page: new ErrorScreen(error: "Hello World"),
          title: "Schedule",
          iconData: Icons.schedule,
        ),
        HomeworkView.page(),
        new Page(
          page: new LoadingScreen(),
          title: "Settings",
          iconData: Icons.settings,
        ),
      ];

  @override
  _MainViewState createState() => new _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  PageController _controller;
  int _index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new PageController(initialPage: widget.initialIndex);
    _index = widget.initialIndex;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  void _handlePageChange(int index) => setState(() => _index = index);

  void _navigateToPage(int index) => _controller.animateToPage(
        index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          widget.pages[_index].title,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontFamily: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.fontFamily,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: widget.pages
            .map((Page page) => new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(
                    page.iconData,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  title: new Text(
                    page.title,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                ))
            .toList(),
        onTap: _navigateToPage,
        currentIndex: _index,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: widget.pages[_index].useFab
          ? new FloatingActionButton(
              tooltip: widget.pages[_index].tooltip,
              child: widget.pages[_index].fab,
              onPressed: () => widget.pages[_index].onPressed(context),
            )
          : null,
      body: new PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: widget.pages.map((Page page) => page.page).toList(),
        onPageChanged: _handlePageChange,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what Page class exactly do?

Comment: Also what does this method do ? CalendarView.page()

Comment: Don't worry about the page class, it just holds some data for the each of the "Pages". CalendarView.page() is a static method, returns my created page for CalendarView.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a bit confused. I do not see you setting up your pages as routes, I have only two pages that I want to navigate between, can you show me a more simplified example using PageView for that in order to understand ?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just check via if-else or switch the current index of tab and perform your action

```
switch (_tabController.index) {
              case 0:
                // Do something for Tab 1
                break;
              case 1:
                // Do something for Tab 1
                break;
              case 2:
                // Do something for Tab 1
                break;
              case 3:
                // Do something for Tab 1
                break;
              case 4:
                // Do something for Tab 1
                break;
            }
```

You need to perform this check every time you are doing changes to your app bar.
This might not be the best approach but it works.