# How to change AppBar colour when another tab is selected using ChangeNotifierProvider on Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I know how to change the colour of the AppBar using tab controller and set state, but every time I click on another tab, all the widgets are rebuilt and my app makes another http.get call. I know that the provider package can be used to only change certain widgets without affecting others by using ChangeNotifierProvider and notifyListeners(). But when I tried to implement this, the colours don't change. I printed the colour to make sure that the method is bring called when I clicked on another tab and sure enough everything seemed to work fine. It seems as though there is a problem when notifyListeners() is called to change the value of color.

Here is the code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ColorChange>(
      create: (context) => ColorChange(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        home: SimpleTab(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

TabController controller;

class ColorChange extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color color = colors[0];

  Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  void changeColor() {
    color = colors[controller.index];
    print(color);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

List<Color> colors = const [
  Colors.green,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.deepOrange,
  Colors.deepPurple,
];

class SimpleTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleTabState createState() => _SimpleTabState();
}

class _SimpleTabState extends State<SimpleTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: colors.length, vsync: this);
    controller.addListener(ColorChange().changeColor);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Tab Demo"),
        backgroundColor: Provider.of<ColorChange>(context).getColor(),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'Green',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Yellow',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Red',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Blue',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Orange',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Purple',
            ),
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
          Container(
            // some future builder using http.get
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327207/changing-the-color-and-text-of-appbar-based-on-the-currently-viewed-page

Comment: That was not what I was looking for. The solution you provided makes use of setstate(), which is not suitable in my case because I don't want to rebuild all the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the "onTap" parameter. Also, you're also returning the same color every time with your getColor() method. Change it so that it returns a different color at different indexes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ColorChange>(
      create: (context) => ColorChange(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        home: SimpleTab(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Color> colors = const [
  Colors.green,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.deepOrange,
  Colors.deepPurple,
];

class ColorChange extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color getColor(int index) {            <-------Changed
    return colors[index];
  }

  void changeColor(int index) {
    Color color = colors[index];
    print(color);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class SimpleTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleTabState createState() => _SimpleTabState();
}

class _SimpleTabState extends State<SimpleTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(length: colors.length, vsync: this);

    //
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Tab Demo"),
        backgroundColor:
            Provider.of<ColorChange>(context).getColor(controller.index),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          onTap: (index) {                   <---------Add this call back
            Provider.of<ColorChange>(context, listen: false).changeColor(index);
          },
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'Green',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Yellow',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Red',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Blue',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Orange',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Purple',
            ),
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
          Container(
              // some future builder using http.get
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to detect a swipe and change the colour of the appbar accordingly, because currently, it is only detecting a tap on the tab.

Comment: Maybe, you want to use PageView for that. Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html